# Foreign collection doesn't seem to be appearing in aggregated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm making a simple forum and want to link two collections so I can display data about the user who made the post on their post:

User.js:

```
_id:60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690
username: testuser
name: test
```

And Createpost.js

```
_id:60d80b1305dcc535c4bf111a
postTitle: "test post"
postText: "aaaaa"
postUsername: "testuser"
```

I was given advice to try $lookup, so I have this:

```
router.get('/forum', async (req,res)=>res.render('forum', {
    newPost: await Createpost.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
         from: "User", 
         localField: "postUsername", 
         foreignField: "username", 
         as: "postUser"
    }
},
{
    $sort: {date: -1}
}  
])}));
```

Then I display it in ejs like so:

```
<% newPost.forEach(newPost => { %>
    Posted by: <%= newPost.postUsername %> - Name: <%= newPost.postUser.name %>
    <%= newPost.postText %>
<% }%>
```

All the data from Createpost.js is working fine, postUsername and postText are being displayed, but when it comes to the data I tried to join, like name, it doesn't show anything. I tried console logging the aggregated data, and it looks like postUser is just an empty array so I suspect it's not getting any data from "User"? But I have no idea what I can do, the collection in mongodb is called users rather than User but putting that in the string instead wouldn't work either.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/eHrR26mcP_n seems to run fine, What happens if you print `newPost.postUser[0].name`?

Comment: It says cannot read name of undefined, and when I try running this code:  const aggregatedpost = await Createpost.aggregate([{$lookup: { from: "User", localField: "postUsername", foreignField: "username", as: "postUser"}}])
 console.log(aggregatedpost.postUser), it says undefined as well..

Comment: Are you sure the collections are under the same database?

Comment: Yeah, in mongodb it shows like this: LHDB > 
createposts
users
votes

Comment: But "users" Isn't different from User?

Comment: Yeah, it's User.js in VS code, but in mongodb, the collection says "users". I thought that might be the problem though so I tried writing "users" in the from: field, but that didn't work either :( I am very lost right now

Comment: if it's an open github repo I could test it

Comment: Yes, i would appreciate that greatly.. https://github.com/chanana96/LiftHelper it's in index.js and forum.ejs

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh, I got it working, I had to write "users" and then newPost.postUser[0].name in ejs.... I tried both of those solutions but not at the same time

Comment: Glad to hear that, good team work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing 'User' as collection name, please check saved collection name in MongoDB. It should be saved as 'users' collection. So, you have to write 'users' in lookup like below code:

```
router.get('/forum', async (req,res)=>res.render('forum', {
        newPost: await Createpost.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
             from: "users", 
             localField: "postUsername", 
             foreignField: "username", 
             as: "postUser"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {date: -1}
    }  
    ])}));
```